# Jquery UI "drop" effect - background move

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I'm trying to do a simple JQuery UI module that shows a menu from left to right with "drop" effect.

I'm using Jquery UI 1.10.3 and Jquery 2.0.3.

My problem: If menu comes from left the menu background jumps from bottom to top and viceversa.

This is my code, you can check my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/yrhTS/

```
> First JavaScript function made an alternative to JQuery deprecated .toggle().
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please help me... anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `padding:2px;` to your `#articleleftmenu` will solve your problem.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrhTS/5/)

**FYI:**

There is a difference between `.toggle()` and `.toggle()  event`

See documentation:

1. [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
2. [.toggle() event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

So you use `.toggle()` normally as below.

```
$('.sections').on('click', function() {
           $( "#articleleftmenu" ).slideToggle( "left" );
});
```

Check this Updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrhTS/4/).

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't understand why the padding is the problem... but your answer solved my problem! Thanks again!

Comment: @MMPP I'm glad that I was able to help.